# From an aspx page, how do I access a dynamically loaded html file's controls?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am loading a dynamic html files (a.html,b.html....) in my aspx page using jquery load page. But i have controls in that html file and i dont know how to set values for that html comtrols from the (code behind of) aspx page..

Ex : jus a outline

**1. Preview.aspx**

```
<body>

<div id="htmlPlaceholder">

             // gonna place the below html file here.

</div>

</body>
```

**2. a.html**

```
  <body>
   <span id="lblNname" runat="server"></span>
  </body>
```

**3. In preview.aspx.cs**

i want to set value for **lblNname**

I hope it makes sense. can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you loading the HTML via JavaScript instead of using .ascx user controls?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible using WebForms.

I would do the following to get around your problem:

1. Load the a.html through AJAX using jQuery.
2. make AJAX requests using jQuery for any data you want to set.

`$(function() {`

...

```
$.ajax('a.html', function(data) {
    $("#htmlPlaceHolder").html(data);


    $.ajax('/path/to/datasource/GetText', function(text) {
        $("#lblNname").text(text);
    });
});
```

...

`});`

Of course you would write some error handling in there to make sure that the data you are getting is what you are expecting before writing it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

An example to set text for the  tag

```
lblNname.InnerHtml = Server.HtmlEncode("Welcome! You accessed this page at: " + DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying
So is it something like this,

```
$('#htmlPlaceHolder').load('a.html',function(){
$.ajax('preview.aspx/GetData', function(text) {
        $("#lblNname").text(text);
    });
});
```

Thanks